# Grails 3 interceptor - unable to set cookie in 'after' method

Tags: grails, cookies, response, interceptor, grails3

In my Grails 3.2 application I found out that cookies set in `after` and `afterView` methods are not set.

My (simplified) controller:

```
class MyInterceptor {

    boolean before() {
        Cookie c = new Cookie('before', 'ok')
        response.addCookie c
        true
    }

    boolean after() {
        Cookie c = new Cookie('after', 'ok')
        response.addCookie c
        true
    }

    void afterView() {
        Cookie c = new Cookie('afterview', 'ok')
        response.addCookie c
    }
}
```

Only `before` cookie is returned in `set-cookie` response header.

Am I missing any kind of limitations of `response` attribute in such methods?

Comment: "Am I missing any kind of limitations of response attribute in such methods?" - No.

Comment: So you'd say it's more like a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is when the `after*` method are invoked the controller or view may have already written to the response such that the response has been committed and it is too late to add any headers or cookies.

This is not a limitation of Grails as such but the just the way servlet containers work.